# Benefits of string compared to char array besides immutability

Tags: arrays, .net, string, char

The [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6650699/2725810) compares `string` vs. `char array` and all the replies give preference to `char array` as far as performance is concerned. On the other hand, some useful functions, such as `split`, are provided for `string`, but not for `char array`, which encourages the use of `string`. What are the benefits of `string` besides immutability (which is not needed in many applications)?

Comment: It's the far more commonly used idiom, mainly **because** of it's immutability. Therefore most APIs only accept `string`

Comment: If you are so concerned about performance that you are contemplating differences between string and char array then maybe .NET is not appropriate tool for your needs.

Comment: @Charlieface Immutability is important for preventing race conditions that do not appear in most applications. So why would it be by far the most used idiom?

Comment: Arguably, ease of use.

Comment: I think that it's a good an object oriented abstraction which hides implementation details effectively. What would you do if your codebase were written using `char[]`, because it's more effective, but later .NET team changes `string` implementation so that it's much faster than `char[]`. If you used the abstraction in the first place, it would much easier to upgrade to benefit with those changes (because you already use `string` and they only changed implementation). In the case of `char[]` upgrade seems to be much harder, `cause you need to update your API.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError My question is precisely why things that make strings easy to use aren't provided for char array.